# How to get token account data from within the on-chain program?

Tags: solana-program, rust

I'm using `get_associated_token_address` to get a token account but how to find out if it is valid or not? Any help please?

```
let payer_associated_token_account = get_associated_token_address(
    payer_account.unwrap().key,
    token_mint.unwrap().key
);

// how to get the data of above ATA?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to access the data of an account, it has to be expected as an account input to the instruction and provided as `AccountInfo`.

Once you have the token account info, it can be deserialized into its appropriate data structure with:

```
let mut data: &[u8] = &info.try_borrow_data()?;
let acc = TokenAccount::try_deserialize(&mut data)?;
```

If you are using anchor, this can all be done for you if you include the account in the instruction's account context struct:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct MyInstruction<'info> {
    // ...
    pub token_acc: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    // ...
}
```

then accessing the token account data within the instruction simply becomes:

```
let amount = ctx.accounts.token_acc.amount;
```

(or whatever data you need to access)

Comment: Is it not possible to get the token account data if I don't pass the token account to instructions? What I want to do is, within the onchain program, I want to do `get_or_create_associated_token_account`. Or at least get the data from within the program, want to be able to only pass the token owner, token mint and token receiver wallet to the on-chain program and then token account creation will happen within the on-chain program. Is that not possible?

Comment: no. this is a runtime limitation of solana where instructions are only provided with the data of accounts that are given as inputs. its helps make on chain contracts deterministic and efficient.

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you!

Comment: One more question @m_callens, how can I access the data of ATA within on-chain program after I passed it to program?

Comment: an associated token account is just a token account. you can use the same code above.